# PHP xmlreader error while installing Zabbix

Tags: php, zabbix

I installed Zabbix 3.4 along with which PHP 7.1 got installed. But I get PHP xmlreader extension missing error. I have enabled xmlreader extension in php.ini file but then too I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Try this `apt-get install php7.1-xml` and verify extension with `php -m`

Comment: I tried this :( Doesn't work

Comment: have you installed that? and what does `php -m` say ? and also check the existence of `/etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini`